# Collecting lists of optionals to a list containing present optionals

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I am trying to refactor some code to return a list of optionals instead of an optional.

I have the following list in my class

```
private final List<Mapper<? extends Message>> mappers;
```

There is a private method that creates features for these mappers and returns a list of message

```
private List<Message> mapToFeature() {
        mappers.stream()
                .map(mapper -> mapper.createFeature())
                .collect(Optionals.toList());
}
```

The Mapper interface looks like this:

```
public interface Mapper<T extends Message> {
    Optional<T> createFeature();
}
```

The `Optionals.toList()` method returns a Collector to filter present optionals into a List.

I want to change the interface (and all the corresponding classes) to return a list of optionals

```
public interface Mapper<T extends Message> {
    List<Optional<T>> createFeature();
}
```

I do not have a method in the Optionals util to filter present options from multiple lists. How would I be able to do the same without making any changes to the util class?

Comment: What *util class* are you referring to?

Comment: It's an internal util package
public static <T> Collector<Optional<? extends T>, ImmutableList.Builder<T>, List<T>> toList() {
        return Collector.of(ImmutableList.Builder::new,
                (builder, optional) -> {
                    optional.ifPresent(value -> builder.add(value));
                },
                (left, right) -> {
                    left.addAll(right.build());
                    return left;
                },
                ImmutableList.Builder::build);
    }

Comment: I still don't understand. You don't want to make any changes to this util class/package, but I don't know what's included in that from what you've posted in your question. Also, there's two identical `Mapper` interfaces shown above.

Comment: Okay, let's assume we have just one method in this util class, the toList method which I just shared. And I want to refactor the code to look like the the second interface `Mapper`. Sorry, I edited the question to reflect what I want the `Mapper` interface to look like.

Comment: The second interface in the question is identical to the first interface.

Comment: Edited that. Sorry about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209022/discussion-between-tanvi-and-jacob-g).

Comment: Why do you want to change the interface to something returning `List<Optional<T>>`? Why don’t you change the interface to something reasonable, like returning just `List<T>`, without empty optionals?

Comment: @Holger, this list is collecting the result from a number of classes which can be returning nulls.

Comment: So let the code which collects these results skip `null` instead of wrapping it.

Answer (score 15):

Collect a stream of `Optional`s to a list containing only the present values:

```
List<Optional<String>> someStrings = ...;

List<String> allPresentStrings = someStrings.stream()
    .flatMap(Optional::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

Since unable to understand your issue properly, it would be better if you will post your util class as well mean while see my go for this:

```
  private List<Message> mapToFeature() {
       return mappers.stream()
                .map(mapper -> mapper.createFeature())
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .collect(Optionals.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Stream<Optional<T>> present = listOfOptionals.stream().filter(Optional::isPresent);

Stream<T> asTs = present.map(Optional::get); 
// this is safe, because all remaining are present,

//convert Streams to Lists as usual with collect.
List<T> listTs = asTs.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: what's a concise way to get the first Optional<T> value, or Optional.empty()
if no value is found?

Comment: filter(Optional::isPresent).first()   You'll have to unwrap the outer optional that first() wraps the result in.

Comment: `You'll have to unwrap ...` - yup, and that's no longer concise...